# convert string to array in php (bullet points as delimiter )

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have text like this

> Day 1:Kochi ( sequence of the Islands differ as per the voyage of
>   schedule.) • Place : Lakshadweep Wharf Near FCI Godown, Report between
>   0900 Hrs to 1000 Hrs • Boarding the ship 0900 to 1000 hrs. • Lunch on
>   board • Departure from Kochi by 1500 hrs. • Evening Tea ,Dinner Day
>   2:Minicoy • Morning Tea, Breakfast in ship • Departure ship by0800
>   hrs. for Minicoy • Arrival at Minicoy 0945 hrs. • Welcome drink, visit
>   light house, sea bath, kayaking, on payment scuba dive. lunch visit
>   village, local residential are, evening tea, Departure 1600 hrs to
>   Ship. • Arrival ship 1700 hrs. Dinner Day 3:Kavaratti • Morning Tea,
>   Breakfast in ship • Departure ship by 0800 hrs. to Kavaratti. •
>   Arrival Kavaratti 0845 hrs. • Welcome Drinks, Glass bottomed boat, sea
>   bath, Kayaking scuba Dive & snorkeling on payment. • Lunch, museum,
>   Aquarium, evening tea. • Departure Kavaratti at 1700 hrs to ship •
>   Arrival Ship 1730 hrs. dinner Day 4:Kalpeni • Morning Tea, Breakfast
>   in ship • Departure ship by 0745 hrs. to Kalpeni. • Arrival Kalpeni
>   0800 hrs. • Welcome Drinks, Snorkeling, sea bath, Kayaking ,
>   snorkeling . • Lunch, Folk Dance, sightseeing, evening tea. •
>   Departure Kalpeni at 1700 hrs to ship • Arrival Ship 1730 hrs. dinner
>   Day 5:Kochi • Morning Tea, Breakfast. • Arrival in Port, leave ship by
>   1100 hrs.

I want to display the string  in an `<li>`.Here is my code for that

```
$items=explode('.',$str);
foreach($items as $item){
  echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
}
```

But this didn't worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is explode on that `•` and then implode the array gluing it together with a `<br/>` tag.

```
$items = implode('<br/>', explode('•', $str));
```

Alternatively you can make those bullet points into true list items like this:

```
<ul style="list-style:disc">
     <?php echo '<li>'. implode('</li><li>', explode('•', $str)) .'</li>'; ?>
</ul>
```

[Here's a working example](https://eval.in/540831)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to explode the string with a period, that is incorrect. Try using this instead it should work perfectly:

```
$items=explode('•',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$items=explode('•',$str);
foreach($items as $item){
  echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$str = "
Day 1:Kochi ( sequence of the Islands differ as per the voyage of schedule.) • Place : Lakshadweep Wharf Near FCI Godown, Report between 0900 Hrs to 1000 Hrs • Boarding the ship 0900 to 1000 hrs. • Lunch on board • Departure from Kochi by 1500 hrs. • Evening Tea ,Dinner Day 2:Minicoy • Morning Tea, Breakfast in ship • Departure ship by0800 hrs. for Minicoy • Arrival at Minicoy 0945 hrs. • Welcome drink, visit light house, sea bath, kayaking, on payment scuba dive. lunch visit village, local residential are, evening tea, Departure 1600 hrs to Ship. • Arrival ship 1700 hrs. Dinner Day 3:Kavaratti • Morning Tea, Breakfast in ship • Departure ship by 0800 hrs. to Kavaratti. • Arrival Kavaratti 0845 hrs. • Welcome Drinks, Glass bottomed boat, sea bath, Kayaking scuba Dive & snorkeling on payment. • Lunch, museum, Aquarium, evening tea. • Departure Kavaratti at 1700 hrs to ship • Arrival Ship 1730 hrs. dinner Day 4:Kalpeni • Morning Tea, Breakfast in ship • Departure ship by 0745 hrs. to Kalpeni. • Arrival Kalpeni 0800 hrs. • Welcome Drinks, Snorkeling, sea bath, Kayaking , snorkeling . • Lunch, Folk Dance, sightseeing, evening tea. • Departure Kalpeni at 1700 hrs to ship • Arrival Ship 1730 hrs. dinner Day 5:Kochi • Morning Tea, Breakfast. • Arrival in Port, leave ship by 1100 hrs.
";

//first convert the bullet to its htmlentity , this is safer
 $str = htmlentities($str);

 //split str
$split_str = explode("&bull;",$str);

//lets rebuild string using loop
$built_string = "";

foreach($split_str AS $str_item){
    $built_string .= "<li>$str_item</li>";
}

//new string list 
echo $str_list  = "<ul>$built_string</ul>";
```

Tested ..